# playing Matroska (.mkv) files via Windows Media Center - no audio

Tags: audio, troubleshooting, windows-media-center, playback, matroska

I'm looking to play my .mkv files via Windows Media Center - I've got it almost working. They show up on the menu, they play video fine, but the audio is mute.
Strangely, if I play the .mkv file via Media Player - the video & audio are fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Windows installation is missing the necessary audio codec for the purpose. Most Media Players come with their own pack of codecs and do not see that problem (Ok, I assume you do not mean the Windows Media Player here).

You could use some tool like [GSpot v2.70a](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) to check if the necessary codecs are installed to play the media file.

Of course, I am also assuming that other media files play well on your Media Center and its only this MKV file which does not play audio.

Comment: +1, Matroska is a container format, not a video or audio codec, it just holds the data. You need a Windows codec for whatever audio format the file has.

Comment: I seem to have the codec, as it plays fine with windows media _player_